# Compare strings in dataframe column according to levenshtein distance with words in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, string-comparison, spell-checking, levenshtein-distance

After using PyTesseract I have a dataframe with words(they are in Greek but it does not matter).
I have also created a list(words_list) that is my custom dictionary ,containing specific words of the topic that I am examining.

What I want to do is,to compare every word in df["no_punctuation"] with every word in the list and

- If the levenshtein distance between the pair of the words is lower than 4, I want to replace the word in the dataframe with the according word from the list
- Otherwise,I want to leave the cell empty

Essentially,it is a step for my own spellchecker however I can not make it work so far.

An image of the dataframe and the list are attached.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmBgd.png)
[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjnnk.png)

What I have tried so far is this :

```
for j in range (0,len(df2)):
    for word in words_list:
        if (enchant.utils.levenshtein(df2["no_punctuation"][j],word)<4):
            df2["new"][j]=word
        else:
            df2["new"][j]=""
```

And as it is presented in the dataframe image,it corrects only the word "generali" and leaves all the rest cells empty.However,there are many other cells that should be completed too.

I have also tried the below,however it produces only empty cells.

```
df2['new']=df2["no_punctuation"].apply(lambda x:"" if (enchant.utils.levenshtein(text,word)>=4 for word in words_list) else word )
```

I think I am close,but still something is wrong.Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for empty cells is the else condition you provided. So, for all comparisons with Levenshtein distance >4 the empty string is entered.
Removing the else condition will definitely solve your problem.

Also, define a new column outside the loop.

```
df2["new"][j]==""
for j in range (len(df2)):
    for word in words_list:
        if (enchant.utils.levenshtein(df2["no_punctuation"][j],word)<4):
            df2["new"][j]=word
```

Comment: How would this code work if the dataframe contains strings (i.e. multiple words) that need to be compared to list of words?