# Levenshtein method to extract data from csv

Tags: python, database, dataframe, extract, levenshtein-distance

I have a csv file where there are product names, manufacturer, id and review on each product. My problem is in two stages:

IMPT: The review column is real customer input so no standardised format. There will be spelling mistakes and 100s of different ways to write the review.

Stage 1: I need to search in the review column if there is any information regarding the expiration of the product. If No, fill NA in that cell and if yes, then leave the column as it is.

Stage 2: If there is any information on the expiration date, get that info into a new column called "Expiration". This column should have the info as to when the product is expiring.

This is the CSV file (I can't upload the csv file but here are some rows to get the gist): [image]

This is what I have done till now:

```
def lev_value(token1, token2):
    #flag = 0
    #count = 0
    for i in token2:
        for j in range(0,len(token1)):
            if (utils.levenshtein(token2, token1[j]))<5:
                #flag = 1
                val = token2
                #print(val)
            else:
                val = "NA"
                count+= 1
                #print(val)
    #print(count)
    return val

my_list = ["expiry", "expiration", "expiring"]
df3 = pd.read_csv("out_test1.csv")

print(lev_value(my_list, df3["Review"]))
```

This gives me an error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What am I doing wrong?

A reference post: [Compare strings in dataframe column according to levenshtein distance with words in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363085/compare-strings-in-dataframe-column-according-to-levenshtein-distance-with-words)

Comment: What is the function signature of `utils.levenshtein` ? I find it weird that you give it a `pandas.Series` as the first argument instead of `i`.

Comment: @rochard4u - sorry I didn't get you. The function is supposed to take in my_list and compare it with the Review column for each row. If it finds any word similar to any word in my_list, it should print that value, otherwise fill it 'NA'

Comment: Check the docs for `utils.levenshtein` - does it really expect the arguments of `(List, String)`? Or do you need to test the Levenshtein distance for each item in my_list?

Comment: @user19077881, okay I will do that and yes, I want that it checks for the first item in my_list, if yes, print the value, no need for further check, if no then check the rest of the items, if not satisfied, print NA. 

Here's a post I referenced from, so I think it should be allowed :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363085/compare-strings-in-dataframe-column-according-to-levenshtein-distance-with-words

Comment: The module DOCs say `enchant.utils.levenshtein(s1: str, s2: str) → int` which is clear as is the example in your Link. You  need to change the code to check two strings and use the checking conditions you describe.

Comment: @user19077881 - I did change my_list = "expiration" but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @user19077881 No, `i` is already an item of token2 so it needs to be used directly.

Comment: @rochard4u Oops! I misread it as an index. As you say it should be used directly in the comparison.